# ecto changeset add assoc for existing

Tags: elixir, associations, ecto

Good morning! I've reached a moment where I'm struggling. To summarize, I'm trying to create a schema/model that has an association where the associated schema/model already exists. Every example I've found looks more like Rails nested attributes. Here is my various code thingses:

The schema (& its changeset function) with the associations:

```
schema "payor_procedure_mappings" do
  belongs_to :payor, Payor
  belongs_to :procedure, Procedure
  field :payor_procedure_name, :string
  field :payor_procedure_id, :string

  timestamps()
end

def changeset(model, params \\ %{}) do 
  model
  |> cast(params, all_params())
  |> validate_required(required())
  |> cast_assoc(:payor, params[:payor])  # <--- LINE 50 from stacktrace
end

defp required do
  :payor_procedure_name,
  :payor_procedure_id
]
```

The pre-existing schema I want to associate with that:

```
schema "payors" do
  field :name, :string, null: :false
  field :polling_url, :string, null: :false

  timestamps()
end

def changeset(model, params \\ %{}) do 
  model
  |> cast(params, all_params())
  |> validate_required(required())
end
```

Here's the code where I'm attempting to set the association:

```
test "valid if all required params are present", %{procedure: procedure, payor: payor} do 
  params = %{
    payor: payor,
    payor_procedure_name: "That one thing we do to patients",
    payor_procedure_id: "2342"
  }

changeset = 
  %PayorProcedureMapping{}
  |> PayorProcedureMapping.changeset(params)   # THIS IS LINE 28 from stacktrace

  assert changeset.valid?
end
```

(Please note that the payor in the second argument to the test function is an already loaded schema/model struct)

To be clear, my params being passed in look like this:

```
%{
  payor: %ReimbursementMonitor.Schemas.Payor{
    __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "payors">,
    id: 12,
    inserted_at: ~N[2020-02-15 16:30:16],
    name: "test_name",
    polling_url: "www.example.com",
    updated_at: ~N[2020-02-15 16:30:16]
  },
  payor_procedure_id: "2342",
  payor_procedure_name: "That one thing we do to patients"
}
```

The situation I've encountered is that if the payor exists already, my tests are really unhappy. I get this error when attempting to run that test:

```
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Keyword.get_lazy/3

 The following arguments were given to Keyword.get_lazy/3:

     # 1
     nil

     # 2
     :with

     # 3
     #Function<5.89690842/0 in Ecto.Changeset.cast_relation/4>

 Attempted function clauses (showing 1 out of 1):

def get_lazy(keywords, key, fun) when is_list(keywords) and is_atom(key) and is_function(fun, 0)
  code: |> PayorProcedureMapping.changeset(params)
  stacktrace:
    (elixir) lib/keyword.ex:223: Keyword.get_lazy/3
    (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset.ex:778: Ecto.Changeset.cast_relation/4
    (reimbursement_monitor) lib/reimbursement_monitor/schemas/payor_procedure_mapping.ex:50: ReimbursementMonitor.Schemas.PayorProcedureMapping.changeset/2
    test/schemas/payor_procedure_mapping_test.exs:28: (test)
```

Full disclosure, I've searched google a ton but the examples I've been able to find are creating or building the payor schema at the time the payor_procedure_mappings is inserted.

I feel like I'm off in the weeds. I'd love to get some pointers of where to go look, good examples of what I'm asking about.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following:

```
# the params that you pass in
%{
  payor_id: 12,
  payor_procedure_id: "2342",
  payor_procedure_name: "That one thing we do to patients"
}

# the changeset function for payor_procedure_mappings
def changeset(model, params \\ %{}) do 
  model
  |> cast(params, all_params())
  |> validate_required(required())
end
```

I think the purpose of `cast_assoc` is to create new associated record(s), which is why you only found examples for doing that. Since you only want to associate the `payor_procedure_mappings` record you are creating to an existing `payor` record, I believe you just need to set the appropriate id.

Answer (score 0):

As it is stated in the documentation for  [`Ecto.Changeset.cast_assoc/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html?#cast_assoc/3)

> `cast_assoc/3` works matching the records extracted from the database (preload) and compares it with the parameters provided from an external source.

That said, the example in the link above is exactly what you need:

```
- |> cast_assoc(:payor, params[:payor])
+ |> cast_assoc(:payor, with: &Payor.changeset/2)
```

The error message also hints there is somewhat `with:` keyword key expected.